# Как связать записи в БД по уникальному id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. В БД есть две таблицы: 
Первая основная таблица "db" содержит поля

```
id(присваивается автоматически),uid,ip,cat,user,region
```

Вторая таблица для дополнительных параметров "db_fields" содержит поля

```
id(присваивается автоматически),massage,field,value
```

И есть вот такие переменные которые необходимо передать в эти таблицы

```
$uid,$ip,$cat_select,$user_name,$region_select,$phone,$photo
```

Первую группу переменных мы передаем в первую таблицу "db" к этой записи автоматически присваивается уникальный id

```
$uid,$ip,$cat_select,$user_name,$region_select
```

Вопрос как передать во вторую таблицу "db_fields" вот эти переменные

```
$phone,$photo
```

да так чтобы в поле "massage" вставился уникальный id из первой таблицы "db" для каждой записи $phone и $photo (коротко говоря привязать телефон и фотографию через id к записи из первой таблицы). Также необходимо для телефона добавить в поле "field" значение 12 а для фото значение 6.

Надеюсь написал понятно) Спасибо

На всякий: вот пример моего кода как я добавляю запись в первую таблицу.

```
  mysqli_query($on_link,"
    INSERT INTO db(uid,ip,cat,user,region) 
    VALUES('$uid','$ip','$cat_select','$user_name','$region_select')");
mysqli_close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для получения последнего сгенерированого значения автоинкрементного поля используйте `mysqli::$insert_id` или `mysqli_insert_id`. Далее полученное значение передавайте во второй запрос.

> Возвращает автоматически генерируемый ID, используя последний запрос

возвращаемые значения, очевидно, привязаны к текущему сеансу и вы получите свой id, а не чей-то другой, кто провел вставку одновременно с вами.

*зы: для передачи параметров в запрос, используйте подготвленные выражения и привязку параметров (http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)*

зы2: код в дополнение

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO db (uid,ip,cat,user,region) 
                               VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $uid, $ip, $cat_select, $user_name, $region_select);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$iid = mysqli_insert_id($link)
```

и далее использовать полученный `$iid` для последующих запросов